# What do you mean "expected type name"in this protobuf error?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Sorry, very new to protobuf. Copy pasting some code and getting an error which doesn't make much sense. Please can anybody help.

```
message person {
  required string name = 1;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME   = 1;
    WORK   = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string    number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type   = 2 [default = HOME];
  }
}
```

The error I get is when I run protoc p2.proto --cpp_out=.:

```
p2.proto:4:1: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
p2.proto:4:1: Expected type name.
p2.proto:10:1: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
p2.proto:10:1: Expected type name.
```

Comment: Any chance this is a whitespace / line ending / encoding / hidden unicode characters / non-printable characters issue?

Comment: @Fanatic23 - I copy/pasted exactly the code in your post into a `.proto` file and it compiled just fine. Are you sure that's exactly the code you tried to compile?

Comment: i run into the same problem as you, did u manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which syntax you using but if it's **proto3** you need to fix some stuff
first of all , due to the related documents and forums ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801257/why-required-and-optional-is-removed-in-protocol-buffers-3)) you don't need to use **required** behind every field because it's pointless, in "protobuf" all fields are considered required by default.
also default values are not allowed in this version.
In the following the most important issue is ,you need to declare your objects explicitly and then reference these objects inside your main model by their assigned names like below:

```
message Person{
    string name = 1;
    PhoneType PersonPhoneType = 2;
    PhoneNumber PersonPhoneNumber = 3;
}
enum PhoneType{
    MOBILE = 1;
    HOME = 2;
    WORK = 3;
}
message PhoneNumber{
    string Number = 1;
}
```

or :

```
message Person{
    string name = 1;
    PhoneNumber PersonPhoneNumber = 2;
}
enum PhoneType{
    MOBILE = 1;
    HOME = 2;
    WORK = 3;
}
message PhoneNumber{
    string Number = 1;
    PhoneType PersonPhoneType = 2;
}
```